# Is it possible to have a mock facebook account to post to?

Tags: facebook

I have an app that I want to use to post to facebook.  However, the app is currently in development and I want to debug it before I start posting to public facebook accounts.  Is there any way that I can create a mock facebook account that I can post to from my app, but the world has no way of looking at it?

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed, see http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/35/

And http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Answer (score 0):

I hope Test Users work for you.  I have not been able to to post to a Test User's wall using the Feed Dialog as described in this question: [Feed dialog error for Test Users](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7879324/).

If you can get it to work for you please let me know how you did it because currently Test Users are pointless without this simple capability.

Comment: I voted for your question because that is exactly what I am trying to do.